# Blazor WebAssembly application fails to debug when pathbase is set

Tags: html, visual-studio, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

## The problem

In a .NET 6.0 Blazor WebAssembly application, when setting `pathbase` in `launchSettings.json`, the debugger fails to attach. Using Visual Studio 2022 (v. 17.0.2).

## The Code

#### wwwroot/index.html

```html
<base href="/app/" />
```

#### launchSettings.json

```json
  "profiles": {
    "MyApp.UI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--pathbase=/app",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "app",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "hotReloadEnabled": false,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7177;http://localhost:5177",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    }
  }
```

Without `"commandLineArgs": "--pathbase=/app"`, the app runs fine and the debugger attaches - although, it's not at the right base path.

With `"commandLineArgs": "--pathbase=/app"`, I get the following error:
[image: Failed to launch debug adapter...unable to launch browser: could not open wss://localhost:7177/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser=...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only workaround I could find:

1. Change debug web browser to chrome, edge throws the error.
2. Change inspect uri to include the subpath:

   "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}**/app/**_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",